# How to add an instance method into a model in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this model:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyModel do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  import Ecto.Query

  # ....
```

How can I add an instance method to it which also uses other field on MyModel? This doesn't work because on an html page it throws an exception saying `the key :my_method not found`

```
defmodule MyApp.MyModel do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  import Ecto.Query

  # doesn't work
  def my_method do
    # how can I get access to "this" or "self" from here?

    "test"
  end
```

Answer (score 11):

Since Elixir is a functional programming language, you don't have methods, you have functions. You also don't have the concept of "instances". There is a [self](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#self/0) function, which is used to identify the PID for the current process, however it shouldn't be confused with "this" which you may be used to in other programming languages.

Functions are always invoked with:

```
module.function(arg1, arg2)
```

So to call the `my_method` function in your example (which I have renamed `my_func`), you would do:

```
def my_func(my_model) do
  my_model.some_attribute
end
```

The thing to notice here is that you must pass the struct as an argument to the function. You would then call this with:

```
foo = %MyModel{}
MyModel.my_func(foo)
```

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html is a great way to learn about the way functions in Elixir work.

Comment: actually, what I'd like is to be able to access it the same way I can access the fields of an object retrieved from a db. So on an html page, I can write `<%= my_item.title %>` But using your approach I can't do the same for "my_func". How should I change it to be able to write `<%= my_item.my_func %>` without having to have that field in a db?

Comment: So you can call the function from your template with `<%= MyModel.my_func(my_item) %>`

Comment: yes, but I'd like to do `<%= my_item.my_func() %>` or `<%= my_item.my_func %>`

Comment: I'm afraid that the language doesn't work that way. I'd recommend going through the getting started guide to get an idea on how functions and modules work.